# Not getting Image from Camera

Tags: android, android-intent

I am sending an intent for camera with a path in Extra. But in result i am not getting the image path. Where i am wrong?

my code is

```
 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
               if (!APP_FILE_PATH_Images.exists()) 
                {
                     APP_FILE_PATH_Images.mkdirs();
                }
             Uri uriSavedImage  =Uri.fromFile(new File(APP_FILE_PATH_Images+ File.separator +
                        "IMG_"+ getTimeStamp() + ".jpeg"));
             cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
             startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

onActivityResult code is:

```
    else if(requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST)
                {
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, proj, null, null, null);
                    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();

                    final String filePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
                    Log.i("File path", filePath+"");
                    cursor.close();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            imageData= new ImagesData();
                            imageData.Source= filePath;
                            imageData.isVector= false;
                            addImage(imageData);
                        }
                    });

                }
```

I am able to get videos with the same code.
Thanks,

Comment: Your App / Camera Activity might not have the right permission. And if you run in on a emulator it might not work either.

Comment: What are you getting in Log - Log.i("File path", filePath+"");

Comment: @KirillKulakov I have given all the permissions. Its working for video recording.

Comment: @SunnyKumarAditya I am getting nothing in log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to get the path back in the result: it would be the one you passed in.  Try using that URI when your result comes back.  (In other words, don't try to read it from the Intent, just save it locally.)  It's not the same as capturing video.  For more information, see: http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html